# Copy changes from an external untracked directory to separate Git working copy

Tags: git, import, version-control, cvs

I have two copies of a project. One uses CVS and the other uses Git repository. Now I have made changes in the project copy that uses CVS and I want those changes to apply on my Git repository too. How can I import changes from CVS-project on the Git repository? Is there a command or built-in mechanism to do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of the `--work-tree` option of the [`git` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git):

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/cvs/project --git-dir==/path/to/your/repo/.git status
git --work-tree=/path/to/cvs/project --git-dir==/path/to/your/repo/.git add .
```

You will consider your CVS content as the working tree of your git repo.

If you are directly in your git repo, then you don't need the `--git-dir` option.

```
cd /path/to/your/repo/
git --work-tree=/path/to/cvs/project status
git --work-tree=/path/to/cvs/project add .
```